# How to transfer data from one collection to another collection

Tags: mongodb, typescript, nestjs

I am working on nestjs.I have two collections i.e collection 1 and collection 2.I want to fetch data from collection 1 and save the same data into collection 2. How do i write the code to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run aggregation pipeline to transfer data like this:

```
db.sourceCollection.aggregate([ { $out : "targetCollection" } ])
```

And if the collection is in another database then use `$merge`